# #1072 - La columna clave 'idMunicipio' no existe

Tags: mysql, sql

Lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de crear una tabla en phpMyadmin   donde debo colocar una llave foranea que es la llave primaria de muncipio pero me sale este errorr #1072 - La columna clave 'idMunicipio' no existe en la tabla , y resulta que la tabla se llama municipio asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y realmente es una primary key

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

trato de ingresar la sentencia asi:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    idClientes INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(idClientes),
    ccCliente INT,
    Nombres VARCHAR(50),
    Apellidos varchar (50),
    Email varchar(50),
    Telefono varchar(50),
    fechaRegistro date,
    Usuario  varchar(50),
    Password varchar(50),
    FOREIGN KEY(idMunicipio)REFERENCES municipio(idMunicipio))
```

pero me sale el error, incluso ya habia hecho tablas con llave foranea y me funciono, hice con el ejemplo que yo tenia y tampoco me dio sera el sistema ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te falta definir el campo `idMunicipio` en tu tabla solo haces la referencia a la tabla `municipio`

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    idClientes INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(idClientes),
    ccCliente INT,
    Nombres VARCHAR(50),
    Apellidos varchar (50),
    Email varchar(50),
    Telefono varchar(50),
    fechaRegistro date,
    Usuario  varchar(50),
    Password varchar(50),
    idMunicipio INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(idMunicipio)REFERENCES municipio(idMunicipio))
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ah funcionado a la perfeccion

Answer (score 2):

El detalle del fallo es que:

Tu llave foránea `idMunicipio` debe estar explícitamente declarada en la entidad `clientes` de modo que cuando tratas de establecer el vínculo entre ella y `Municipios` se pueda construir.

Debes proceder de este modo:

- La entidad Municipios debe tener una llave primaria (*esto ya lo tienes cuando declaraste `idMunicipio`*)
- La entidad `clientes` debe tener una columna que servirá como llave foránea que podemos llamar `municipio_id` y que debe ser del mismo tipo de dato y longitud de la llame primaria mencionada en el punto anterior (*esto no lo tienes aún hecho*), entonces justo después de donde declaras a la columna `password` deberás poner lo siguiente

  ```
   municipio_id INT(11) NOT NULL
  ```
- Posterior creas el *constraint* para unir ambas tablas declarando la llave foránea (*esto ya lo tienes hecho*)

Opcionalmente:

Te recomiendo declares al constraint con un nombre para que posterior te sea mas fácil identificar cuales son las entidades vinculadas en este mismo, pudiera quedar así:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_clientes_municipios FOREIGN KEY(municipio_id) REFERENCES municipios(idMunicipio)
```

Finalmente quedando así:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes(
    idClientes INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(idClientes),
    ccCliente INT,
    Nombres VARCHAR(50),
    Apellidos varchar (50),
    Email varchar(50),
    Telefono varchar(50),
    fechaRegistro date,
    Usuario  varchar(50),
    Password varchar(50),
    municipio_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_clientes_municipios FOREIGN KEY(municipio_id) REFERENCES municipios(idMunicipio)
)
```

**Referencia**

- [Te recomiendo leas el ejemplo a detalle ofrecido en la documentación oficial de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-examples)

Comment: Me gusta más esta respuesta por el simple hecho de ponerle nombre al constraint. Siempre será mejor controlar el nombre, pensando en actualizaciones futuras